# Convert IList<string> to MVC.SelectListItem needs explicit casting

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, list, linq-to-objects

I am calling a project (WCF, but that shouldn't matter) that consumes a IList , with MVC 3 (which really should not matter either obviously) I want to convert a single column List of strings (IList  which is just a list of Countries)  into a List

Hard Coded list I have done like this and they work fine:

```
 public List<SelectListItem> mothermarriedatdelivery = new List<SelectListItem>();
 mothermarriedatdelivery.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Yes", Value = "1" });
```

However, now I am trying to convert this code:

```
 public List<SelectListItem> BirthPlace { get; set; }
 BirthPlace = new List<SelectListItem>();
 GetHomeRepository repo = new GetHomeRepository();
 BirthPlace = repo.GetCountries();
```

I need to implicitly convert from the List to SelectListItem, anyone do this?  Yes.. I have search and found several examples, but none that really fit my specific need.

Comment: You cannot convert a collection (IList) into a single item (SelectListItem).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use LINQ as such:

```
BirthPlace = repo.GetCountries()
                 .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x, Value = x })
                 .ToList();
```

Or I think you can just use one of SelectList's constructors:

```
public SelectList BirthPlace { get; set; }

BirthPlace = new SelectList(repo.GetCountries());
```

Comment: Cool, that worked (Linq) but not the second part.  I am however having "fun" with razor.   Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem'   -  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BirthPlace, Model.BirthPlace as SelectListItem)

Comment: Fixed that razor problem.  Thanks again Laurent!

Answer (score 0):

In Controller ,

```
   var result = proxy.GetAllLocations();

   ViewBag.Area = result.Where(p => p.ParentId == null).Select(p => new SelectListItem { Text = p.LocationName, Value = p.LocationId.ToString() }).ToList();

   ViewBag.Locations = result.Where(p => p.ParentId != null).Select(p => new SelectListItem { Text = p.LocationName, Value = p.LocationId.ToString() }).ToList();

   return View();
```

In View ,

```
@Html.DropDownList("LocationName", ViewData["Area"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```